# Perl regular expression to modify a filename

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to remove the Ist part and last part of the file name. 
I have a filename like  `/external/prop/new/test/File.Name.will.BE.this.extension.date`
I want to remove the first part of the directory (`/external`)  and the last part of the filename extension (`.date`)  so my output file name would be `/prop/new/test/File.Name.will.BE.this.extension`

eg:

- OLD  FILE name:   `/external/prop/new/test/FACL.Prop.for.BBG.txt.09242012`
- NEW FILENAME: `/prop/new/test/FACL.Prop.for.BBG.txt`
- OLD  FILE name: `/external/prop/old/test/set2/FACL.Prop.FITCH.csv.09242012`
- NEW FILENAME:  `/prop/old/test/set2/FACL.Prop.FITCH.csv`

I had tried something like

```
my($FinalName, $Finalextension) = split /\.(?!.*\.)/, substr($Fname,$Flength);
```

but it is not quite helpful.

`/external` will always remain the same but the date will always vary and I can't just remove the numbers as the .extension can be numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Fname =~ s|^/external||;  # Remove leading "external" from path
$Fname =~ s|\.\d{8}$||;    # Remove date from end of filename
```

Comment: Some explanations what you are doing and why?

Comment: @markus-tharkun  - I am trying to generate file names in the target directory based on the files exist in the staging directory.

Comment: also the extension varies as its .date

Comment: Sorry, I saw "external" and saw "extension", fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $qfn = '/external/prop/new/test/FACL.Prop.for.BBG.txt.09242012';
$qfn =~ s{\.[^.]*\z}{};  # Remove last "extension".
$qfn =~ s{^/[^/]+}{};    # Remove first part of path.
```

Comment: Some explanations what you are doing and why?

Comment: @markus-tharkun, What the OP said. Because the OP asked. Added inane comments. (This type of documentation does not belong in line-by-line comments.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex which captures the text you need in `$1`:

```
^\/[^/]+(.*?)\.\d{8}$
```

This assumes your date is always 8 numbers. You can replace the last `\d{8}` with your appropriate date regex.

This can be tested in [RegExr here](http://regexr.com?328m4).

**Regex Break-up:**

- `^\/` matches the beginning of the line followed by forward slash
  (escaped)
- `[^/]+` matches all text until it finds the next forward slash (to
  mark the end of `/external`)
- `(.*?)` matches AND captures non-greedily all text you need until it finds the last of the pattern
- `\.\d{8}$` matches the last period followed by 8 digit date followed by end of line